# MySQL - counter query

Tags: mysql

Have two tables users and user_demographics

**users has the basic structure of (does have more fields but not needed here)**:

```
id  name    email            gender   age   ethnicity
1   test1   test1@test.com   1        1     1
2   test2   test2@test.com   1        2     1
3   test3   test3@test.com   2        3     2
4   test4   test4@test.com   3        1     1
5   test5   test5@test.com   2        4     5


**Gender**: 
   1 - Male, 
   2 - Female, 
   3 - Prefer not to say

**Age**: 
   1 - 16-20, 
   2 - 21-24, 
   3 - 25-30, 
   4 - 31-24

**Ethnicity**: 
   1 - White, 
   2 - Black, 
   5 - Prefer not to say
```

and so on and currently have around 1000 users.

**user_demographics structure is**:

coreid, type, option (for the sake of this question 'type' will be text, just to make it clearer)

```
coreid, type        option
1       gender      1
1       gender      2
1       age         1
1       age         3
1       ethnicity   1
2       gender      2
2       gender      3
2       age         3
3       gender      1
```

On a web based form I have 3 sets of checkbox lists, one for each option gender, age, ethnicity and the a user can select multiple from each.  They click update and these details are stored in the mysql database as above.  coreid is related to another table, but not relevant here.

What I'm trying to do is get a total count of users for each coreid regardless of what type it is.  The count should get smaller the more options you select.  So coreid 3 should have the biggest count because I've only selected one option.

Example: coreid 3 is selecting all males

Example: coreid 2 is selecting all (females AND 'prefer not to say') AND age range 25-30

Struggling on how to create a single query that will give me the results I need, hope this makes sense.

The idea behind the over all system is that we have a large form that a user fill outs and we store in the information in the users table.  Then a member of the admin team can go in and select these users by selecting options from the various demographics information we have collected.  So they might just want to see everyone that has ticked the gender options of 'male' and 'prefer not to say' for example.  Another admin member may go in and say they want all males, between the age of 25-30.  Or they could just tick all options under gender.  The idea is that they can select any combination and get a list of results.  At the minute I just need to get a count back for the combination selected.

Comment: It might be helpful to post the expected output and also the query you have tried

Comment: to add to @B001ᛦ you should also explain the numbers in the `gender, ethnicity` columns because it not clear in this context what they mean.. for example `1` in the gender column can be male, female or unknown?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think those are values.. The column names are `coreid, type, option`

Comment: sure @B001ᛦ but it doesn't explain what the number or values  `1, 2 ,3` in the column `gender` or the numbers or values `1, 2, 5` in the `ethnicity` columns mean or represent

Comment: Yes, you are right @RaymondNijland

Comment: "(females AND 'prefer not to say')" -- that doesn't make much sense as a user can select only one gender and that cannot be two values at once. So such a condition would always produce an empty set.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you want to do. What is the meaning of `coreid` in your application?

Comment: @stickybit - from the front end that is correct they can only select one option.  From the admin side of things, a member of the team can select various combination to get their results. I've updated my question to hopefully be a little bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

By the SOUNDS of it, you are probably going to need to do with dynamic SQL where you actually build the query on-the-fly, then execute that.  Also, to clarify what I THINK you are asking is as follows.  CoreID is like a set of filters that some manager is interested in getting count and or details of specific users.  They are interested in

```
EITHER gender condition (1 or 2)
```

AND EITHER age condition (1 or 3)
AND just the one ethnicity

to possibly target products that might hit those demographics.  So you would pre-query every record for CoreID = 1 then start building your query.  You would want to order your query by the TYPE to group common items such as the gender, age, ethnicity categories.

Then, within your either localized code (not indicated such as C#, VB, java, whatever), you would need to build the query in such a way that you parenthesis OR those within same category, and logical AND between different such as

```
where
      (    Gender = 1
        OR Gender = 2 )
  AND (    Age = 1
        OR Age = 3 )
  AND (    Ethnicity = 1 )
```

If you are trying to write as a MySQL stored procedure, it would be a type of dynamic SQL query... either way, the WHERE clause needs to be constructed from the Core criteria someone is looking for.

You are correct, the last one would be easiest for CoreID = 3 would be a simple

```
WHERE ( Gender = 1 )
```

Clarify language source and I or others might be able to offer additional direction, but if I am accurate, you should try to write your own first pass of code, but I will shoot out a pseudo-code for you something like

Get Records Ordered for one CoreID, order by the type of criteria.

```
prep variable identifying if pending open Parenthesis
prep variable identifying last "type" building for.

for each record

  If new type
     if has Open Parenthesis
        add closing paren
        add logical AND before the next entry we are getting

     add open parenthesis
     set flag we have open parenthesis

  else
     since same type as last type, add logical OR

go to next record, repeat.

If after last record we would always need to close parenthesis even if a single criteria
```

Comment: thanks for your response and you are correct in what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm using PHP and MySQL, I was hoping to be able to do this without creating an a dynamic SQL query, but I'm starting to think this might be the only way.  Thought there might be some magic SQL query that I would be able to create with MySQL.

I'll trying creating a Dynamic query and see how that goes.  Many thanks

Comment: @Martin, you MIGHT be able to do this if you are absolutely SURE of the limited conditions... let me think on it some though...  Are these criteria ranges you supplied  the full scope? or just the basics.

Comment: these are just the basics, there is going to be around 50 demographic data sets to collect, but once I've got a head start the rest should be easy enough to add.  Thanks again